# How to set collection as content in csv file export

Tags: csv, export, magento2.1.0

I am using **magento 2.1** version. I am working to built export csv functionality on frontend. I am using below code:

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
       \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
    ) {        
        $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        $this->fileFactory           = $fileFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Order view page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();
        $block = $layout->createBlock('Vendor\Modulename\Block\Myblock');

         //do your custom stuff here
        $fileName = 'mytest.csv';
        $this->fileFactory->create(
            $fileName,
            null, //content here. it can be null and set later 
            DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
            'application/octet-stream', //content type here
            null
        );
        $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        $resultRaw->setContents($block->getCollection()); //set content for download file here

    }
```

How can I set collection to content in export file?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,
replace `$resultRaw->setContents($block->getCollection());` with below

```
foreach($block->getCollection() as $data){
    $tmp = implode(",",$data->getData());
    $resultRaw->setContents($tmp);
}
```